# Can't understand why I can't edit my html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap Twitter and I've an issue there :

```
<body>
<div class="container col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2 main-progress-bar-container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="progress sm-progress-bar active">
        <div class="progress-bar" id="main-progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
            <!-- value here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Page content -->
<div class="container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 main-container">
    <!--Left Part (2/3)-->
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="left-part">
        <div class="part-content" id="left-part-content">

        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Right Part (1/3)-->
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="right-part">
        <div class="part-content" id="right-part-content">
            <div id="clock-container">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I update my code like this :

```
<!-- Page content -->
<div class="container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 main-container">
    <!--Left Part (2/3)-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="left-part">
        <div class="part-content" id="left-part-content">

        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Right Part (1/3)-->
    <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="right-part">
        <div class="part-content" id="right-part-content">
            <div id="clock-container">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or like this :

```
<!-- Page content -->
<div class="container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 main-container">
    <!--Left Part (2/3) TEST-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="left-part">
        <div class="part-content" id="left-part-content">

        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Right Part  REMOVED -->

</div>
```

Nothing change.. And when I'm looking at my source code in my browser, the code is not updated. On the server, the code is updated. I've the same trouble in local.. then I don't understand. I've tried with another browser, to clear the cache, history, to change the path, etc. Nothing change. It has been updated only when I've removed the whole div main container, then I've nothing to displayed unless my progressbar (as expected).

That's stange. There's someone able to explain me what I've missed ? I'm pretty sure it's a begginer mistake. Thanks.

Edit : I'm starting to belive in ghosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes you are deleting are related to the responsiveness of the site. If the screen size changes, or if the device changes, they would perform the update of the site to fit the screen.

You could also, post a picture of what you see, it can help us to understand what it looks like.

Another thing, you have no content inside your divs, so the website won't show anything if the css is empty or so.

Comment: The problem is not the responsiveness of the site, it's the update of my code. Look at the 2d code section of my post. I've edited : "<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="left-part">" into "<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="left-part">" but when I examine my code with a right click on the element, I've still the first version, before the edit. Maybe I've misunderstood your answer.

Comment: There : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/34/5/1503655855-toto.png
The black part is the code on my server, the second it's why I can read in my browser. Even I relaunch my browser, clear the cache, etc. Same issue in local.

Comment: My question may sound a little bit stupid but before you checking the code with the right click, have you reloaded the page on the browser? Are you looking at the right file on the browser? Sometimes when working with multiples files we may load a file on the browser and edit a similar but that is in a different location.

Comment: Yes. I've tried on a different browser, or on a colleague browser (who has never visit the website). Nothing happends. It's the correct page because if I try to add something like "<script> alert("hello!");</script>", it's displayed.
And if I delete the whole container, all is removed from my browser, as expected.

Comment: Can you update your question and post some more information? I am very curious right now to understand what is happening.

Comment: Ok I just find the problem. A colleague has created a javascript function which recreated the DOM for a good reason in the context from a template.. when you launch the page. And it's hard coded. God, sorry to took some of your time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you have deleted the right part, the div is aligned in such a way. It's the Bootstrap feature

Answer (score 0):

What I am telling is possibility. There might be something else also.

If your code is not being changed by all those efforts then only thing that can control your HTML code is **Java Script**. It can control your **HTML DOM**.

Any of your JavaScript function might be reconstructing or editing your HTML code.

Hope this helps.